# Regex to get the text between two identifying text blocks

Tags: regex

I have some XML that I want to replace.

Below, I want to replace `"Alarm"` within `<Alarm name="Alarm">` with the `name` of the `Tag` to which it belongs.
E.g. for the first `Tag` below, the `Tag` `name` is "Buffer Tank Pig Catcher Equipment Fault"
So the `Alarm` `name` would need to be set to "Buffer Tank Pig Catcher Equipment Fault" as well. I plan to use notepad++, so I need to use capture groups in order to put it all back together.

I have a regex saved on regexr: regexr.com/58ac5

```
(<Tag name=)("[\w\d\s]+")( path="Alarms"[\w\d\s=">\r\n</\-;\[{}\]!@#$%^&*+(),\.]+<Alarm name=)("[\w\d\s]+")
```

But it's not returning the right results. It captures the correct start, but it matches up until the very last Tag's `<Alarm name="..."` in the XML (if you add more than two of the tag elements you'll see that it gets to the last Tag element before finding the <Alarm name="..." part and ending the capture). It's not capturing each Tag individually.

So my question is, how can I capture the text in between the two text blocks (e.g. `<Tag name="Tag Name" path="Alarms"` and `<Alarm name="Alarm"`) for ***each*** Tag element?
(what should this part be replace with? `[\w\d\s=">\r\n</\-;\[{}\]!@#$%^&*+(),\.]+`)

Thanks in advance!

```
<Tag name="Buffer Tank Pig Catcher Equipment Fault" path="Alarms" type="OPC">
     <Property name="Value"/>
     <Property name="DataType">6</Property>
     <Property name="OPCServer">Ignition OPC-UA Server</Property>
     <Property name="OPCItemPath">ns=1;s=[{PLCName}]{DeviceName}_Trfer.Alm.11</Property>
     <Property name="EngUnit">%</Property>
     <Property name="PrimaryHistoryProvider">SQLServer</Property>
     <Property name="HistoryMaxAgeMode">5</Property>
     <Property name="HistoryMaxAge">4</Property>
     <Alarms>
        <Alarm name="Alarm">
           <Property name="setpointA">1</Property>
           <Property name="priority">3</Property>
           <Property name="ackMode">1</Property>
           <Property name="label" bindtype="Expression">&apos;{InstanceName} {TagName}&apos;</Property>
           <Property name="displayPath" bindtype="Expression">replace(replace(replace(
 {itemPath}
 
,{System/Site Name} + &apos;/&apos;, &apos;&apos;)
,&apos;/Alarms/&apos;, &apos;/&apos;)
,&apos;/&apos;,&apos; &apos;)</Property>
        </Alarm>
     </Alarms>
  </Tag>
  <Tag name="Low Flow Alarm" path="Alarms" type="OPC">
     <Property name="Value"/>
     <Property name="DataType">6</Property>
     <Property name="OPCServer">Ignition OPC-UA Server</Property>
     <Property name="OPCItemPath">ns=1;s=[{PLCName}]{DeviceName}_Trfer.Alm.15</Property>
     <Property name="EngUnit">%</Property>
     <Property name="PrimaryHistoryProvider">SQLServer</Property>
     <Property name="HistoryMaxAgeMode">5</Property>
     <Property name="HistoryMaxAge">4</Property>
     <Alarms>
        <Alarm name="Alarm">
           <Property name="setpointA">1</Property>
           <Property name="ackMode">1</Property>
           <Property name="label" bindtype="Expression">&apos;{InstanceName} {TagName}&apos;</Property>
           <Property name="displayPath" bindtype="Expression">replace(replace(replace(
 {itemPath}
 
,{System/Site Name} + &apos;/&apos;, &apos;&apos;)
,&apos;/Alarms/&apos;, &apos;/&apos;)
,&apos;/&apos;,&apos; &apos;)</Property>
        </Alarm>
     </Alarms>
```

Update:
I found a situation where this doesn't quite work, if there are `<Tags>` that don't have an `<Alarm>` element, it keeps returning until it finds a `<Alarm>` element within another `<Tag>`. So it could have multiple finds of `<Tag>` elements which is incorrect. Basically I don't want it to return the purpley-blue highlighted section below:
https://regexr.com/58pi5
I need to discard the find if it encounters a closing `</Tag>` element before it finds the `<Alarm..>` element. I've tried negative lookbehind/ahead, and can't get it working..
[image]

Comment: You absolutely should be using an HTML/XML parser here, _not_ pure regex.

Comment: XML is not a regular language. Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job. [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4642212).

Comment: It seems like I should use an XML parser for the sake of humanity... I assume it's going to be something I have to code up myself, using an xml library?

Comment: change the second `+`  to `+?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tim Biegeleisen is correct, you should not be using regex for this.

In Python it is only a few lines of code to use the built-in XML parser to get what you need. Note, however, that your file must be valid XML, meaning it must have a root element and all tags must be closed. Your sample is missing a `</Tag>` at the end and does not have a root element, so I've added those.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlString = """<Document>
 <Tag name="Buffer Tank Pig Catcher Equipment Fault" path="Alarms" type="OPC">
 <Property name="Value"/>
 <Property name="DataType">6</Property>
 <Property name="OPCServer">Ignition OPC-UA Server</Property>
 <Property name="OPCItemPath">ns=1;s=[{PLCName}]{DeviceName}_Trfer.Alm.11</Property>
 <Property name="EngUnit">%</Property>
 <Property name="PrimaryHistoryProvider">SQLServer</Property>
 ... # etc
 </Document>""" # added

root = ET.fromstring(xmlString)
# or if opening from file:
# tree = ET.parse('your_file_name.xml')
# root = tree.getroot()

for tag in root.findall('Tag'):
  tagName = tag.get('name')
  for alarm in tag.iter('Alarm'):
    alarm.set('name', tagName)

newTree = ET.tostring(root)
print(newTree.decode())

with open('output.xml', 'wb') as outputFile:
  outputFile.write(newTree)

# or use tree write method if opened file to begin with
# tree.write('output.xml', encoding="unicode")
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/StableSvelteProcedures#main.py)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the code and your time :) Also happy it's in Python as that's what I've been these days

Answer (score 0):

Your middle term (with the giant character class) has a quantifier of `+`, which is *greedy* and so will match/consume everything possible (including any intermediate terminating blocks) while still matching.

Change the quantifier to `+?`, which is *reluctant* and so will match/consume a *little* as possible while still matching, so preventing it from skipping over potential terminating text blocks.

See https://regexr.com/58aev

Comment: I didn't know there was such a quantifier. Very good to know! Thanks :)